# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos que cree por defecto en sqlite, en un listview? ANDROID

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

espero se encuentren bien, y espero que alguien me pueda ayudar por favor, lo más urgente posible si está dentro de las posibilidades.

Les cuento, quiero visualizar en un listview, los datos que tengo ingresados de forma directa en SQLite, y me ha costado demasiado, cabe mencionar que no tengo clases creadas, ni nada, está todo directo de la base de datos, de verdad les agradecería de sobremanera que me ayudaran.

Les adjunto mi clase de conexión.

```
package com.example.taller_final;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DB {
    //TABLA USUARIOS
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NOMBRE = "_nombreusuario";
public static final String KEY_PASS = "_pass";

//TABLA RECETAS
public static final String KEY_RECETA = "_idR";
public static final String KEY_NOMBRER = "_nombreR";
public static String DATABASE_TABLE_R;

public final String DATABASE_TABLE_I="Ingredientes";

private final String DATABASE_NAME="BD";
private final String DATABASE_TABLE="usuarios";
private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public String[] estructura(){
    String[] recetas = new String[6];
    recetas[0] = "CREATE TABLE Recetas(id INTEGER, NOMBRE TEXT)";
    recetas[1] = "INSERT INTO Recetas VALUES(1, 'PANTRUCAS')";
    recetas[2] = "INSERT INTO Recetas VALUES(2, 'TALLARINES CON CARNE 
MOLIDA')";
    recetas[3] = "INSERT INTO Recetas VALUES(3, 'CAZUELA')";
    return recetas;
}


private Context ourContext;
private DBHelper ourHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public DB(Context ourContext) {

    this.ourContext = ourContext;
}


public DB open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return  this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}



public String getUsuarios(){
    String [] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NOMBRE, KEY_PASS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRowID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOMBRE);
    int iPass = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASS);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        String id = c.getString(iRowID);
        String name = c.getString(iName);
        String pass = c.getString(iPass);

        result = result + id + ": " + name + " " + pass + "\n";
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}

public long guardarUsuarios(String nombreUsuario, String pass){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NOMBRE, nombreUsuario);
    cv.put(KEY_PASS, pass);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}


public static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static Cursor rawQuery;

    private String DATABASE_TABLE = "usuarios";
    private String DATABASE_RECETAS = "recetas";
    private String DATABASE_INGREDIENTES = "ingredientes";

    //USUARIO
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NOMBRE = "_nombreusuario";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "_pass";

    //RECETAS
    public String[] estructura(){
        String[] recetas = new String[6];
        recetas[0] = "CREATE TABLE Recetas(id_recetas INTEGER, NOMBRE_RECETA 
    TEXT)";
        recetas[1] = "INSERT INTO Recetas VALUES(1, 'PANTRUCAS')";
        recetas[2] = "INSERT INTO Recetas VALUES(2, 'TALLARINES CON 
    SALSA')";
        recetas[3] = "INSERT INTO Recetas VALUES(3, 'CAZUELA')";
        return recetas;
    }

    //INGREDIENTES
    public String[] estructura1(){
        String[] ingredientes = new String[6];
        ingredientes[0] = "CREATE TABLE Ingredientes(id_ingrediente INTEGER, 
    NOMBRE_INGREDIENTES TEXT)";
        ingredientes[1] = "INSERT INTO Ingredientes VALUES(1, 'TOMATE')";
        ingredientes[2] = "INSERT INTO Ingredientes VALUES(2, 'HARINA')";
        ingredientes[3] = "INSERT INTO Ingredientes VALUES(3, 'CARNE')";
        return ingredientes;
    }

    //R/I
    public String[] estructura2(){
        String[] RI = new String[6];
        RI[0] = "CREATE TABLE RI(id_recetas INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
    Recetas, id_ingredientes INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Ingredientes)";
        RI[1] = "INSERT INTO RI VALUES(1, 2)";
        RI[2] = "INSERT INTO RI VALUES(2, 1)";
        RI[3] = "INSERT INTO RI VALUES(3, 3)";
        return RI;
    }


    private final Context ourContext;
    private DBHelper ourHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;



    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ourContext = context;
    }

    public DBHelper open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //CREAR TABLA USUARIOS
        String sqlCode = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NOMBRE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(sqlCode);

        //INTENTO DE CREAR TABLA RECETA
        String sqlCode1 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_R + " (" +
                KEY_RECETA + " INTEGER PRIMERY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NOMBRER + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(sqlCode1);



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

        //DROP RECETA
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_R);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public Cursor validarUsuario(String usu, String pas){
        Cursor mcursor = null;
        mcursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("usuarios", new String[] 
    {"_id", "_nombreusuario", "_pass"},
                "_nombreusuario like '" + usu + "' " + "and _pass like'" + 
    pas + "'",
                null, null, null, null);

        return mcursor;
    }

    public Cursor recuperar(int idReceta, String nombreReceta){
        Cursor cursor = null;
        cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("recetas", new String[] 
    {"id_recetas", "nombre_receta"},
                 "id_recetas like '" + idReceta + "' " + "and nombre_receta 
    `introducir el código aquí`like'" + nombreReceta + "'",
                  null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Lo último, del cursor recuperar, es como me imagino que puede ser, pero no sé si en su totalidad este bien, espero de verdad que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Desde ya, ¡muchas gracias!